# Why do VUSA and S&P 500 have different trend?

Tags: united-kingdom, stock-markets, etf

I am checking S&P 500 and VUSA to start investing in the stock market. However I've seen that VUSA is not showing the same trend as the S&P 500. I understand that VUSA is in GBP, which implies currency rate, however the trend is quite different. Shouldn't they be trending the same way?

[image]

Comment: They look to trend the same in the period when both markets are open.

Comment: "VUSA is not showing the same trend as S&P500" — How did you arrive at that conclusion based on 3-4 hours of chart data?

Comment: The chart in this question is a beautiful illustration of my answer to the linked question: "So more specifically, it should be possible to make a chart of the...index and of the ETF (using say 15-minute bars) on a 24-hour-per-day UTC time axis... At some times, only the index is quoted; at times, only the ETF is quoted; at times, both; at times, neither. The combined chart should show bars nearly overlapping when both are present. That is, up to tracking error, the available quotes from each source are partial windows onto a common underlying 24-hour price action."

Comment: And to make the charts literally "overlapping" as I state, the numbers plotted should not be percent changes from different starting points (due to the different time zones), but rather actual prices rescaled (1) for currency conversion and (2) to reflect how many "shares" of the S&P 500 are owned by each share of VUSA.